# How to highlight selected polygon in interactive map, made in tmap package in R?

Tags: r, r-leaflet, tmap

For example, I made a simple `leaflet` based map using `tmap` package. The result is an html with interactive map, showing some polygons of buildings (find data, code and the map itself [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1sV4Vo5iJrNVU_X1CQwBtxxA5m7gWMnX4)).

I want polygons to be highlighted someway when selected by html user by mouse click, like it is in QGIS (screenshot adjusted). Is there a way to do such thing in R?

[image: selection highlight in QGIS]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may consider switching over to library(leaflet)

```
map <- tm_shape(buildings) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "#ff00bf")

leaflet(data = buildings) %>% 
  addPolygons(highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "yellow",
                                                  weight = 2, 
                                                  fillColor = 'yellow', 
                                                  bringToFront = TRUE))
```

[image: leaflet example]